# BIM 360 issue "Assigned To"

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

How can I change "Assigned To" from specific user to unspecified? I used `{name: '-'}` mainly for my UI which is obviously not enough to be used as input, perhaps `{id: '', name: '-'}` or `{id: null, name: '-'}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update 2023-Jun

BIM360 issues API just released v2 API. Now it supports filtering `assignedTo`, `assignedToType` and `displayId` (in v1 called identifier). See here for the announcement: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360-issues-version-2-api-released-1

- Find the unassigned issues

```bash
curl --location --request GET 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/issues/v2/containers/:issueContainerId/issues?filter[assignedTo]=null&filter[assignedToType]=null' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '
```

- Find an issue by its `displayId` (in v1 called identifier)

```bash
curl --location --request GET 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/issues/v2/containers/:issueContainerId/issues?filter[displayId]=14' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '
```

=========

We can specify `null` values to both `assigned_to` and `assigned_to_type` to remove the user from the issue and make it be unspecified.

```json
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/issues/v1/containers/:issueContainerId/quality-issues/:issueId' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json' \
--data-raw '{
    "data": {
        "type": "quality_issues",
        "id": "{{issueId}}",
        "attributes": {
            "assigned_to": null,
            "assigned_to_type": null
        }
    }
}'
```

API ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-:id-PATCH/

Comment: thanks Eason, i'll try your method later,
another related question is what if i want to filter out unspecified from "Assigned To"?, below is one of the issues which is assigned to specific user {id: 'b26c083a-ab54-4dad-9b83-e68ef46362ff', email: 'bim_1-16@mtr.com.hk', name: 'BIM16 - Consultant Project Team', firstName: 'BIM16 - Consultant', lastName: 'Project Team', …},
in short, what should i specified in my filter object? {name: '-'} is obviously not enough for sure.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, do you want to get all issues assigned to this user you pointed out? If yes, try to call [GET issues](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-GET/)?filter[assigned_to]={{userUID}}

Comment: if issues are assigned to user/role/company then i can filter correctly, but if issues are not assigned yet then how to get those (unspecified) issues? i used {name: "-"} which is obviously not enough

Comment: Sorry, what does the { name:’-‘ } stand for?

Comment: i added just for my filter UI.
0: {name: '-'}
1: {id: 'b26c083a-ab54-4dad-9b83-e68ef46362ff', email: 'bim_1-16@mtr.com.hk', name: 'BIM16 - Consultant Project Team', firstName: 'BIM16 - Consultant', lastName: 'Project Team', …}

Comment: just a thought, perhaps i don't have to specify in req.query.assigned_to, just "manually" specify null for both assigned_to and assigned_to_type at server-side when "-" is selected at client-side, right?

Comment: So, { name: ‘-‘ } is your wildcard filter in your apP that you want to get all unassigned issues of BIM360?

Comment: exactly, useless in actual filtering at server-side, just for my filter UI at client-side

Comment: so my question is how to specify filter at server-side for "unspecified" of issue's "Assigned To"

Comment: Ok, it seems unsupported since I cannot search unassigned issues on BIM360 UI with my tests, either. Let me double-check with our engineering team, and will get back to you A.S.A.P. However, please note currently it's writer break, so the response will have some expected delay. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: sure, thanks Eason for your help, very appreciated!

Comment: hi Eason, any feedback from engineering team? will be great if this can be fixed soon, any tangible date, say within 3 months? also, "former user" needs to be considered too, seems API treats "former user" as special "unspecified"? thanks

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I hate to disappoint you, but the `Assigned To` filter of v1 API is unsupported.

Comment: @bim2016 Sorry for letting you wait for so long. I updated my answer above. Now BIM360 issues service has the v2 API. You can filter issues with more filters.